# "Caps Lock on" message is shown for too long. How can I make it disappear sooner?

Tags: 11.04, notification, capslock

The "Caps Lock on" warning message is shown for too much time on Ubuntu 11.04.

Could anyone tell me how can I reduce the time this message is displayed for, please?

Comment: Where do you get this message? if you mean where you are asked for your password (synaptic for example) it is there for as long as you have caps lock on and then disappears when you disable it - at least for me. Unless it has a timelimit that i have never met since i usually press it in a second or two

Comment: @Chriskin: when I just press caps lock, the notification message comes at the top right corner. It is there for around 3 seconds even after releasing the caps lock key. It is really annoying if I am writing code on a terminal that covers the top right corner.

Comment: sorry then, i can't reproduce it to help in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use Pinguy OS, right? Pinguy OS comes with some Compiz settings which display NotifyOSD notifications for caps lock, num lock, etc.

Anyway, even if that's not the case, you can get NotifyOSD to be displayed for a shorter period of time by installing the patched NotifyOSD by Leolik (by default, NotifyOSD doesn't support setting the amount of time the notification is displayed) using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
pkill notify-osd
```

As far as I know, the script to display NotifyOSD notifications for caps lock has a NotifyOSD timeout value set so there shouldn't be anything else to do. However, if you use some other way to display NotifyOSD notifications for caps lock, make sure the script uses "--expire-time=VALUE" so the time they are displayed is less then 10 seconds (that's default).

For more info about the patched NotifyOSD, see: [Configurable NotifyOSD Bubbles For Ubuntu 11.04: Move, Close On Click, Change Colors And More](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html)